# Git (GitLab) one Project-Base multiple customers

Tags: git, version-control, branch

is it possible to have a GitProject for multiple customers with some other features?

For example, i start a website project in Git.
Then one of my customers wanna have some fancy stuff in his website, that is not necessary for the other customers.

How would i implement and commit/push that feature so the others don't see it?

Maybe, another customer also wanna wana have some customizing, then it get's realy complex i think. 
Not least, if i have a bug in the core, how would i commit the hotfix, so every customer get it?

Thank you,
Kevin

* edit *

thx to kpopovb

but how coul i merge different branches/features to one new Master?

For example this is my Project, i wanna do a release for customer1 with everything including the "hiddenFeature1" and a release for every other customer (without hidden feature). superFeature is a Feature for everyone.

how would i do it?

```
                         /--[hiddenFeature1]
                        /               
[v0.1]-----[v0.7]-----[v1.0]------[v1.3]-----[v1.5]
              \           /
               \         /
                \       /
               [superFeature1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different branches for every feature e.g. feature1, coolstaf2, fancy stuff ...etc., of your website an also you can create multiple master branches for every costumer e.g. master-costumer1, master-costumer2, ... etc.

Than all you need is to merge the staff you want in the branch of the costumer that order it.

Like Linus Torvalds says on his presentation about git, use as many branches as you wish merging code with git is quite easier than any other version control system.

Comment: ok, i think i have to learn, how to create a seperate master, and organize the branches that are inside?

Comment: nope master is just the default name of the main branch in git something like trunk in svn. You can name your branches as you wish and you can merge them as you wish. And you decide which branch is main and which is for some costumer or which is a feature branch.